# Using interp1 in an ODE function [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, parameters, parameter-passing, ode, interpolation

I have here an ODE to solve that has a test parameter ***a***.
I would like ***a*** to be a function of temperature *T* (in this code it is solved as ***X(2)*** since it varies with time).

I would like to base it off experimental values of *a* and *T*.

Hence, I am thinking of doing it along the lines of *interp1*.

Here is my test dummy ODE.

```
function xprime = RabbitTemp(t,X) 

% Model of Rabbit Population
% where,
%       Xo = Initial Population of Rabbits
%       X(1) = Population density of Rabbit
%       X(2) = Temperature T (that varies with time) 
%       a = test parameter

% Interpolate here
Texptdata = [1 2 3 4];
aexptdata =[10 14 19 30];
a= interp1(Texptdata,aexptdata,X(2),'spline');

% ODE

dx = [0 0];

dx(1) = (X(1))*(1 - X(1)*a - 3*(X(2))));
dx(2) = sin(t);


xprime = [dx(1) dx(2)]';

end
```

I've tried running the code with my solver and it does compile fine.
However I am just wondering if the ODE solver is calling the correct interpolated ***a*** corresponding to the correct corresponding value of ***X(2)***. I cannot seem to figure out how to verify this.

Can anyone help me verify this or point me to how I can go about doing it? Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it seems correct to me. The only `a` variable you have in your function is the interpolated one, so it is the only one that can be called. Out of interest, why are you using `spline` interpolation?

Comment: @am304 Thanks! I chose `spline` arbitrarily. I've read that there is `pchip` too. I'm sure there are some differences, but I haven't gotten around to reading what exactly it is. Would you mind sharing some insights with me if you have any?

Comment: All the interpolation methods are listed in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#inputarg_method). Given your data, I was wondering whether a simple linear interpolation might be sufficient.

Comment: I see where you're coming from now. This is a dummy ODE with dummy data I created for learning purposes. Thanks once again.